# Differences of pragma: no-cache and Cache-Control: no-cache

Tags: java, browser-cache, cache-control, pragma

I have two identical instances of the Java EE Application deployed in two different servers. However, in server A (HTTP, pragma: no-cache), page refreshes fine while in server B (HTTPS, Cache-Control: no-cache), page refreshes with old data retained. I'm curious about the difference since it's the only obvious difference in the headers sent.

Comment: This has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers