# Difference between Pragma and Cache-Control headers?

Tags: http, http-headers, request, protocols, httpresponse

I read about *Pragma* header on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) which says:

> "The Pragma: no-cache header field is an HTTP/1.0 header intended for
>   use in requests. It is a means for the browser to tell the server and
>   any intermediate caches that it wants a fresh version of the resource,
>   not for the server to tell the browser not to cache the resource. Some
>   user agents do pay attention to this header in responses, but the
>   HTTP/1.1 RFC specifically warns against relying on this behavior."

But I haven't understood what it does? What is the difference between the `Cache-Control` header whose value is `no-cache` and `Pragma` whose value is also `no-cache`?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

`Pragma` is the HTTP/1.0 implementation and `cache-control` is the HTTP/1.1 implementation of the same concept. They both are meant to prevent the client from caching the response. Older clients may not support HTTP/1.1 which is why that header is still in use.

Comment: Although the answer of cnst below is much more complicated, it is also much more correct according to the specification. `Pragma: no-cache` is intended to be used only in requests (meaning "I want the original, not a cached copy") and its behaviour is not specified for responses.

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-cache` has the same meaning for requests but is actually also defined for responses, meaning "If you want to use a cached copy of this in future, you must first check with me that it is up-to-date (i.e. perform revalidation)".

Comment: It is for Cache Control, it does not have to be ONLY for cache-preventing, it can also be used to say "You can cache this." ....

Comment: Basic answer. To get it more complicated: It's also a request header which means you can send no-cache to the server too. And that actually might mean to returning stale content to the clients, WHAT?? Now you forget this and read the above simple answer and enjoy your life, don't dig it too hard lol

Comment: _They both are meant to prevent the client from caching the response_ is a confusing note for readers. It can also have `max-age` which doesn't prevent caching. It just sets an expiration date for it...

Comment: @clime cache-control: no-cache doesn't have same meaning. `The no-cache directive means that a browser may cache a response, but must first submit a validation request ` cache-control: no-store is the one that has the same meaning.

Answer (score 112):

There is no difference, except that `Pragma` is only defined as applicable to the requests by the client, whereas `Cache-Control` may be used by both the requests of the clients and the replies of the servers.

So, as far as standards go, they can only be compared from the perspective of the client making a requests and the server receiving a request from the client.  The http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32 defines the scenario as follows:

> HTTP/1.1 caches SHOULD treat "Pragma: no-cache" as if the client had
>   sent "Cache-Control: no-cache". No new Pragma directives will be
>   defined in HTTP.
>
> ```
>   Note: because the meaning of "Pragma: no-cache as a response
>   header field is not actually specified, it does not provide a
>   reliable replacement for "Cache-Control: no-cache" in a response
> ```

The way I would read the above:

- if you're writing a client and need `no-cache`:

  - just use `Pragma: no-cache` in your requests, since you may not know if `Cache-Control` is supported by the server;
  - but in replies, to decide on whether to cache, check for `Cache-Control`
- if you're writing a server:

  - in parsing requests from the clients, check for `Cache-Control`; if not found, check for `Pragma: no-cache`, and execute the `Cache-Control: no-cache` logic;
  - in replies, provide `Cache-Control`.

Of course, reality might be different from what's written or implied in the RFC!

Comment: What if the header has both? `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` and 
`Pragma: no-cache`? Which one will then be honored by the modern browsers?

Comment: @PKHunter, why would you care which way it goes if the behaviour is undefined?  If you're responsible for the server, clearly you can do better than give out misleading information to the client.  Also, as pointed in my answer, the `Pragma: no-cache` is only defined for requests from the browser, and it would thus be entirely invalid and undefined in replies from the server to the browser, e.g., I'd imagine that every single browser (whether modern or not) should ignore such a header in any reply it may receive.

Comment: A modern browser should ignore the Pragma in favor of Cache-Control if both are present because the latter can specify time periods and other information that was not available in the initial 1.0 protocol.

Answer (score 31):

tl;dr: `Pragma` is a legacy of HTTP/1.0 and hasn't been needed since Internet Explorer 5, or Netscape 4.7. Unless you expect some of your users to be using IE5: it's safe to stop using it.

| Stop using *(HTTP 1.0)* | Replaced with *(HTTP 1.1 since 1999)* |
| --- | --- |
| Expires: [date] | Cache-Control: max-age=[seconds] |
| Pragma: no-cache | Cache-Control: no-cache |

If it's after 1999, and  you're still using **Expires** or **Pragma**, you're doing it wrong.

I'm looking at you Stackoverflow:

> ```
> 200 OK
> Pragma: no-cache
> Content-Type: application/json
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> X-Request-Guid: a3433194-4a03-4206-91ea-6a40f9bfd824
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
> Content-Length: 54
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 19:03:12 GMT
> Via: 1.1 varnish
> Connection: keep-alive
> X-Served-By: cache-yyz8333-YYZ
> X-Cache: MISS
> X-Cache-Hits: 0
> X-Timer: S1522782193.766958,VS0,VE30
> Vary: Fastly-SSL
> X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
> Cache-Control: private
> ```

---

- **Expires:** `[date]` *(deprecated - HTTP 1.0)*
- **Pragma:** no-cache *(deprecated - HTTP 1.0)*
- **Cache-Control:** max-age=`[seconds]`
- **Cache-Control:** no-cache *(must re-validate the cached copy every time)*

And the conditional requests:

- **Etag (entity tag) based conditional requests**

  - **Server:** `Etag: W/“1d2e7–1648e509289”`
  - **Client:** `If-None-Match: W/“1d2e7–1648e509289”`
  - **Server:** `304 Not Modified`
- **Modified date based conditional requests**

  - **Server:** `last-modified: Thu, 09 May 2019 19:15:47 GMT`
  - **Client:** `If-Modified-Since: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 10:49:23 GMT`
  - **Server:** `304 Not Modified`

last-modified: Thu, 09 May 2019 19:15:47 GMT

Comment: The RFC says you should use them both in case a client doesn't support Cache-Control: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#page-29

Comment: The *client* *"ought to"* include both - unless it wants to treat HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/1.0 caching servers differently. The server should not include `Pragma` at all. *(In HTTP/1.0, Pragma was defined as an extensible field for implementation-specified directives for recipients.  This  specification deprecates such extensions to improve interoperability.)*

Comment: From a security standpoint, it is recommended to use it. Many browsers follow the pragma: no-cache directive, so it is advised to use it by OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Application_Security_FAQ#How_do_I_ensure_that_sensitive_pages_are_not_cached_on_the_user.27s_browser.3F

Comment: @RandallBorck: You are spreading outdated (by two decades, no less!) information. *No*  browsers follow the Pragma directive any more, unless it's 1999. This is cargo cult advice: "it doesn't hurt and we've always done it, therefore it's good and necessary."

Comment: @Piskvor Most servers still support both 1.0 and 1.1, so unless you actively block HTTP/1.0 requests you don't choose which protocol the client is using. Most developers today don't bother to block 1.0, hence it is still a best practice, even in 2019.

Comment: I'm confused how it can be "best practice" while doing virtually nothing. In what case would this header have any effect, @RandallBorck? It seems like if a user is already using an ancient, unsupported browser it's already going to be riddled with security holes, so why spend money and time talking about and implementing this? "It's easy to do" is not a good reason to do something useless.

Comment: @DavidS if you are actively blocking HTTP/1.0, then just use Cache-Control. If you allow HTTP/1.0 requests then it is also your responsibility to follow the security best practices for that protocol and include the Pragma header too. If you don't know that you can block HTTP/1.0, then design your site to support it. I don't think there is anything wrong with blocking HTTP/1.0 and dropping the header, but if you advertise and serve a client protocol you have a due diligence obligation to make it secure for that client, even if you don't like their choice of protocol.

Comment: SO has stopped serving Pragma and now solely relies on cache-control.