# IE8 attachment download issue over SSL

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-8, download, attachment

While downloading excel file on IE8 over SSL, we are getting error: "Unable to download Document.ashx from MyHostName.Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later."

We tried couple of solutions, but none of them worked except regedit(which is not viable).

1)Tried the registry edit as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308 and it worked. But, this is not a viable solution.
2) Tried the solution as per this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815313 where they say the files will download if you ‘copy shortcut’ and run it on via the browser URL. But, this solution was not consistent and worked sometimes but mostly did not work.

3) Update our java controller code to response.setHeader("Cache-Control", " must-revalidate, private "); response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1) but still when we look at the header it shows as "cache-control: no-cache". this solution is also not working

4) Un-Check the Option to ‘Not Save Encrypted files to Disk” on IE 8 Browser. But that also not working. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/21/internet-explorer-may-bypass-cache-for-cross-domain-https-content.aspx  and
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549423

also searched on internet with various options suggested as above, but none of them are working full proof.

if anyone has solution other than listed above. please do share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I discovered, that a header:

```
Pragma: private
```

will fix this.

Comment: This was the solution for me, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "**no-store**" and "**no-cache**" occur in your header in that order. IE8 pukes if it's reversed.

Check out the update at the end of this post: [Internet Explorer Cannot Download https://something](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx)

I found that I needed to also remove the "pragma" header to make it work. Apparently, pragma is not intended for responses although I don't know if any old browsers out there require it.

Source: [Difference between Pragma and Cache-control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the server sends to the browser an http header that disables caching, Explorer gives an error. We also tried all the solutions you said without luck, but analyzing the http response we saw that the application server added `no-cache= "Set-Cookie"` http header automatically and it disabled IE8 caching... There is a setting that can be made on the AS but in our case we could not do it, so we changed our cookie-management code server side and we resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and following entry resolve this problem

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-xls; charset=utf-8");

response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+filename);

response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3800");