# how to force all browsers to not store your site's cache?

Tags: html, caching, nginx, page-caching

When you are in the development stage it's a bit embarrassing to constantly remind your clients to clear the cache or to ask them to "refresh the page a bunch of times."

Is there a setting that I, the developer, can set in nginx or as a meta tag in the HTML to force all browsers to stop caching my page?

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but pretty darn similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, according to [Difference between Pragma and Cache-control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers/15050018#15050018) and also http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32, the following may be sufficient, in nginx:

```
add_header  Cache-Control   no-cache;
```

In practice, you might have to specify some extra directives; it would seem like using the [`expires`](http://nginx.org/r/expires) directive should be sufficient, which will automatically add the `Cache-Control` header as above, too:

```
expires -1;
```

Comment: @Ramin, of course; it's even possible to use it in an `if` within a `location`.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting these headers:

```
"Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
"Expires: Mon, 26 Jun 1997 05:00:00 GMT"
"Pragma: no-cache"
"Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"
```

This will prevent the browsers from cashing the pages.