# Prevent user going back and viewing previously submitted form Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a payment page and when the user submits, it captures the payment and directs to a thank you page. The problem is that when the user clicks back, the browser takes them back to the previously submitted page with the payment form and all.

How can i prevent the user from accessing the previous page?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

@James, put this method in your application controller and call this method on before_action callback like -

```
before_action :set_cache_buster
```

and then define the action in protected method like ->

```
protected

def set_cache_buster
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "#{1.year.ago}"
end
```

To accomplish this we just need to disable browser caching using appropriate HTTP headers. Here’s the secret:

**Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store**

Taken individually, each of these Cache-Control attributes would seem to prevent caching. In practice, no-cache and no-store are usually interchangeable in most browsers. However for the back button cache specifically, Firefox will only disable this cache if no-store is specified. To play it safe and guarantee cross-browser compatibility, you should use all four attributes.

For more info see the link - [Difference between Pragma and Cache-Control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers)

For specific page:

Add that callback on the specific page with the only option like:

```
before_action :set_cache_buster, only: [:your_action_name]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Since this is in my app controller won't it affect caching on all pages and not just the payment page? Cheers

Comment: yes, for specific page you can add that filter on that page!

Comment: how exactly is that done for a specific page? should i put it in my custom controller action for that page?

Comment: yea, so i've tried this and it doesn't work locally. i can still hit the back button and view the previous page and the info entered

Comment: Which action should this be applied to? the `GET Checkout` where the form is filled out, the `POST Process` where the transaction data is processed, and/or `GET Thank_You` the post processing page that they shouldn't hit the back button from.