# AJAX in Internet Explorer 11 - Don't cache

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have an issue with AJAX in the IE 11. My page is asking sone values via AJAX form the server using this code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
  {
    doSomeThing();
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "theURL", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

In Chrome and Firefox it's working fine but the IE seems to cache the AJAX response and I get the same result, even if the page on the server changed.

Is there a way to disable the caching?

Comment: append a random number on your ajax request/respond url

Comment: or just fix your server to not tell your client to cache.

Comment: Also, don't use w3schools as a resource. Or else we'll be supporting IE5 'till the end of time (and no, supporting IE5 isn't by far the worst offence of theirs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a random parameter to the url, such as a timestamp:

```
var url="//yoururl.com/";
url+="?"+new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy. I tried many cache busting techniques and setting cache headers. So many of these either did not work or were wild goose chases. The only solution I found which tested to work correctly was setting:

Header Pragma: no-cache

I hope it saves others with IE headaches.

BTW this is StackOverflow thread is great to shed light on the difference between Pragma and Cache-control:
[Difference between Pragma and Cache-control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers)