# New versions of html files not being served

Tags: django, django-templates, gunicorn

I'm using a combination of nginx, gunicorn and django. All works fine except that new versions of html pages are not being served. The old pages continue to be served. I've tried restarting gunicorn and nginx and rebooting the server. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap [This is for Chrome, but you get the idea]

It's a cache killer for your browser.

You can also use a no cache header on the webserver [Difference between Pragma and Cache-control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers)

You can also clear cached files from your browser, but that only solves the issue until it caches the file again.

Comment: Turns out it is not a browser cache problem, but you did make me recheck other changes where I found my error. Thanks.