# How to measure if the option "Disable Cache" is active in Chrome (via javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am willing to create a Chrome Extension which alerts the user if the option `Disable Cache` is disabled because one could run unwillingly against the cache.
Is there a way to measure in javascript (maybe Chrome Extensions API?) if the Chrome DevTools option `Disable Cache` is active?
Is there a certain header added to requests?

Comment: You can inspect the requests in devtools network panel. I see `cache-control: no-cache` header there so it should be possible to detect it using chrome.webRequest API. Read the documentation and look for examples on using the API if needed.

Comment: Well I can't seem to find proper documentation about the `Disable Cache` option. Also over here it's the `Pragma: no-cache` header. Chrome 79.0.3945.117

Comment: Oh ok, they're both there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers

Comment: There's no documentation for the option, I meant chrome.webRequest's documentation.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to be sure that headers are sufficient to rely on. Shall I answer the question or close?

Comment: Yeah this might come useful later, as @wOxxOm said, post something what you came up with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can detect the `cache-control: no-cache` header via the `chrome.devtools.network` api with the `.onRequestFinished` event.